# Applications of topology to discrete dynamical systems?

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems

I'd like to know some of the applications of topology to discrete dynamics. By discrete dynamics I loosely mean studying maps between discrete sets.

I mean cases where adding a topology to the sets or enlarging them to topological spaces enables one to use topological methods to either prove a new result about the behavior of the maps or give a new proof of an old one.

No-go theorems (that a topological method won't be of any help for a given problem) would be interesting as well.

Comment: Possibly a google search for [Ethan Akin "discrete" dynamical systems](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ethan+Akin+%22discrete%22+dynamical+systems) will lead to something.

Answer (score 1):

You will find much of that in 
Neil Hindman and Dona Strauss, **Algebra in the Stone-Cech Compactification**---Theory and Applications. Series: De Gruyter Textbook.